# Token to Read Code from a Single Repository

Tags: azure-devops

Is it possible to create a token for read-only access to a single repository within VisualStudio.com Team Services?

I see I can use a [Personal Access Token](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/auth-overview) to limit access to a Team Services Server, but it appears to be for the entire server rather than a single repository.

Surely, there must be a way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn’t the Token for a Single Repository level, but Personal Access Token permission is based on the user who created.

So, you can refer to these steps below to generate a personal access token for your requirement:

1. Add an additional user to your VSTS instance
2. Logon your VSTS with that account and create a Personal Access Token.
3. Logon your VSTS with your own account and remove some permissions for that account (e.g. just grant necessary permission for a repository)

After that, this Personal Access Token can just access a Single Repository

Comment: What's the best way to create a service account for this if my VSTS instance is linked with AzureAD? I seem to recall that anyone in your AzureAD gets some type of default access within an O365 tenant, correct?

Comment: @Doug Could you register a new Microsoft account (e.g. hotmail) and add it to your VSTS?

Comment: Year's later and this is still appears to be the answer :-(. Trying to figure out the best way to have a build routine be able to only perform actions on a given repo. Creating a whole user opens up all sorts of security holes. I'd think Microsoft would have a way for something like this.